# Bash setting variable with command value

Tags: bash, variables

```
        #echo $LINE |cut -f"${arg}" -d' '
    pom=$LINE |cut -f"${arg}" -d' '
```

I have this two lane. First is working but second not. I want to variable get a value of this command cuz i want use this value like string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run the first line, then assign the value returned to the variable. You do this with the command inside backticks, like this:

```
pom=`echo $LINE |cut -f"${arg}" -d' '`
```

The reason the second line doesn't work, is because whats in `$LINE` is most probably not a valid command, and pipes takes outputs from commands, which is why you need `echo` to output the contents of `$LINE`.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of code is discouraged :

```
pom=`echo $LINE |cut -f"${arg}" -d' '`
```

in favor of :

```
pom=$(echo "$LINE" | cut -f"${arg}" -d' ')
```

The backquote (`) is used in the old-style command substitution, e.g. foo=`command`. The foo=$(command) syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside $() is less surprising, and $() is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Answer (score 1):

If there are no empty fields in LINE (i.e. no repeated spaces), you can also use pure bash:

```
ITEMS=($LINE)
pom=${ITEMS[arg]}
```

Note that $arg is zero based in this case, so you might need to use [arg-1].